# Post to facebook and unlock levels

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I'm programming my own iPhone game and since I don't want the users to pay for my levels, I'd like to allow them to post something on their FB or twitter timeline. Once it's done, I'd like to unlock the level for free, and do that for each levels pack.

Anyone has an idea on how to do this ? I know I can use Facebook API for iOS to post a status, but how can I ensure the action has been done ?

Comment: Isn't app going to be rejected when not allowing all the features in the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Each post or tweet has a confirmation delegate method. Add an NSNotification to unlock your level on confirmation completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, it's easy using graph api for FB.

You can say user to post message hardcoded in you code and you receive response from api that message is posted on his wall then you can unlock the level.

Also if you want that user can't edit message then you need to post message in background and it easy like below code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictPara = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictPara setObject:objSelGameStep.smsg forKey:@"message"];
[dictPara setObject:@"status" forKey:@"type"];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:dictPara andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

i hope this may help you.